# Count characters of multiple columns

Tags: postgresql, char

I have a table with 15 columns (text).
I counted the number of characters for every column with char_length and stored it in a view. Now I want to sum up these results. 
In some fields of the table were is currently no text so these fields are are NULL/empty. If I now sum the result fields of the view (integer) only rows are calculated where all 15 columns are filled.

```
SELECT C1+C2+...+C15 FROM view;
```

I tried also these approaches (without using the view):

```
SELECT char_length(C1)+char_length(C2)+...+char_length(C15) FROM T1; 
SELECT char_length(C1||C2||...||C15) FROM T1;
```

How can I count characters of multiple columns (per row)? Even if some columns are currently not filled.

Comment: *NULL* or *empty*, that's a decisive difference. Your expressions would work with empty strings, but not with NULL.

Comment: Excuse me please. The fields are empty. I thought postgresql treats this as NULL. The dataset was imported from a .csv file.

Comment: No. `''` (an empty string) is something different than `NULL`

Answer (score 4):

The `concat()` function will treat a `NULL` value as an empty string:

```
select char_length(concat(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5))
from t1;
```

It will also implicitly cast any non-character value to a string, so even if one of the columns is e.g. an `integer` this will work.